# "Error in file" instead of "Error in eval" when specifying output file in knit2html

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am making several html reports from one Rmd file called "template.Rmd".
When using the function knit2html(), there is a misleading error message, "cannot open the connection", while in fact the error is due to a code mistake, such as a missing variable. Let me illustrate by a little example below:

Template.Rmd contains this inline R code:

```
`r missing_variable`
```

When I don't specify the output file, I get a useful error message

```
> knit2html("docs/template.Rmd")
Quitting from lines 2-4 (docs/template.Rmd) 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'missing_variable' not found
```

When I specify the output file, I get a misleading error message

```
> knit2html("docs/template.Rmd", "docs/template.html")
Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
cannot open file 'docs/template.html': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
cannot open the connection
```

Is this a knitr related problem?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem with the most recent versions of R and **knitr** on CRAN, but in most cases, you do not need to specify the `output` argument, and it is strongly not recommended to use an output path that contains a directory name, such as `docs/template.html` (see the Note section in `?knit`). In your case, just switch the working directory to `docs` and run `knit2html()`, e.g.

```
setwd('docs')
knit2html('template.Rmd')  # generates template.html
```

Comment: From one template I want to generate several output files. Each output file needs a different name. [Hadley]() and yourself recommend to avoid using setwd() in a script. That is why I try to avoid using it. At the moment I am using      
`setwd("docs"); tryCatch(knit("template.Rnw"), finally= setwd(project_dir))`

Comment: To clarify, we recommend not to use `setwd()` _inside_ the Rmd document, or _before_ `knit()`, instead of avoiding `setwd()` completely. There are certainly many legitimate cases in which `setwd()` are necessary and useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... The note section in `?knit` says that _"it is strongly recommended to be in the current working directory"_. I don't understand really why `knit2html()`'s output path shouldn't contain a directory name, but I have the feeling that there must be a strong reason . It's a pity that you cannot reproduce the errors I mentioned in my question. ... to create multiple html reports from one .Rmd template, I will then `setwd()` in the `/docs` directory and use `file.copy()` after each `knit2html()` to rename each output file.

Comment: The reason is the external dependencies. For example, an HTML file may depend on external images (by default under the `figures/` directory under the current working directory, say, `~/wd/`); if you write the output HTML file to `docs/foo.html`, the image `<img src='figures/bar.png' />` will not be found, because the HTML page will look for `~/wd/docs/figures/bar.png`, but the image is really at `~/foo/figures/bar.png`. Same thing applies to CSS, JS, and cache files, etc. If you `file.copy()`, you need to consider these dependencies, although **markdown** will base64 encode images by default.